# Looping Function to convert rows to column untill empty Row

Tags: r

I have data which was web scraped and I face a serious challenge with its format, which I am trying fix with out much success, here is how the data looks

```
df<-as.data.frame(c("aa","ab","ac"," ","ba","bb","bc"," ","ca","cb","cc"," ","da","db","dc"))
```

and what i am trying to do is to transpose each set until blank value to columns and make data frame look like this,

```
a<-as.data.frame(c("aa", "ab", "ac"))
b<-as.data.frame(c("ba", "bb", "cc"))
c<-as.data.frame(c("ca", "cb", "cc"))
d<-as.data.frame(c("da", "db", "dc"))
df.new<-as.data.frame(c(a,b,c,d))
t(df.new)
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a grouping variable with `cumsum`, `split` the column and `rbind`

```
i1 <- df[,1]==" "
m1 <- do.call(rbind, split(as.character(df[,1])[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1]))
as.data.frame(m1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  V1 V2 V3
#0 aa ab ac
#1 ba bb bc
#2 ca cb cc
#3 da db dc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=as.character(df$a)
y=!grepl("\\s",x)
z=ave(y,cumsum(!y),FUN=cumsum)
unstack(stack(by(x,z,as.character)[-1]))
  X1 X2 X3
1 aa ab ac
2 ba bb bc
3 ca cb cc
4 da db dc
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.